# How to play video from application bundle in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a video in my iPhone application documents directory. I am want  to play that using mpmovieplayercontroller. can some one post code to do this.

Thanks,
Naresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the docs for mpmovieplayercontroller:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/initWithContentURL:

It's as simple as creating a url to the local file using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ofType:]
```

Then passing this url into:

```
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:]
```