# Play a video file present in resources of app bundle using opencv in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, video

Kindly let me know how to play a video file which is located in app bundle or in video app folder using opencv in iPhone / iPad.

I have gone through some or URL's [Video files in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936058/video-files-in-opencv) but i didn't get to know specifically for iPhone.

Thanks.

Comment: look at this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014504/how-to-play-video-from-application-bundle-in-iphone

Comment: I want to play the video file using OpenCV and not using iOS MPPlayer.